# Дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо» — с большой или с маленькой буквы?

Tags: прописная

Как правильно: Дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо» или дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо»?

Answer (score 2):

```
  Как правильно: Дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо» или дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо»?
```

Если это официальное название, то **ГБУ РК "Дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо»"**(государственное бюджетное учреждение), если неофициальное название - то **дворец-замок «Ласточкино гнездо»**.